# Remotely configuring BIND

Tags: bind, remote-access

What is an easy way to programmatically add new zone files and change the BIND configuration from a remote server?

Comment: SSH is the key. (What a pun.)

Comment: @rdineiu the question is very vague, we really can't tell what you're trying to do. Please see [ask] for details. Also, asking for the "best" is argumentative, everyone's got an opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest and arguably easiest is to connect to the server via a console like SSH (or telnet if you really don't care about security) then changing the configuration files with your favorite CLI editor (eg emacs or vi).

BIND also has has `rndc` which allows for certain administrative tasks. If BIND is backed by a database, then you can directly edit the database.

There are [some web GUIs](http://www.google.com/search?q=bind%20web%20gui) that can be installed and configured to administer BIND, but generally require quite a bit of setup; most of which may be very foreign to someone looking for an "easy" way to configure a DNS server.